# How to measure data transfer between FreeBSD server and client workstation?

Tags: freebsd

I have a FreeBSD 7.3-RELEASE-p2 server communication with various workstations (it is mainly a subversion server). I need to measure the amount of data that is transferred from my server to one specific client.

If possible I would like to do this using base system utilities, but any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ipfw count rules:

```
ipfw add 00008 count tcp from 10.1.1.1 to me
ipfw add 00009 count tcp from me to 10.1.1.1
```

Also you can use NetFlow(ng_netflow), trafd or ipcap.

Comment: Using ipfw make sure you don't already have rules n°8 and/or n°9 or ipfw will group those rules and if you have to delete one of them later you'll lost the others.

Comment: Yes, using ipfw count rules is exactly what I was looking for. Using sh, awk and crontab I get daily accounting in csv files that can be visualized and processed fürther. Thanks for pointing out the obvious ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try http://iperf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: iperf is useful for benchmarking connection speed, but does not provide usage accounting, which is what the questioner is asking for I believe..